# Common jdbc update query using Java

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm writing a update query using jdbc. But based on the condition I have to set different values to a column. Can this code be modified as a simpler code? Please let me know your ideas.

```
if(allDealsCreated) {
   System.out.println("Updating the status of the deals as CLOSED");
    if(deals != null && !deals.isEmpty()) {             
        for (String dealId : deals) {
            PreparedStatement closedPreparedStatement = null;
            try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:as400://localhost/BB", 
                "<username>",
                "<password>")) {

            String sql = "<Update query to set status as closed>";
            closedPreparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            closedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
} else {
System.out.println("Updating the status of the deals as NEW");
if(deals != null && !deals.isEmpty()) {             
    for (String dealId : deals) {
        PreparedStatement newPreparedStatement = null;
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:as400://localhost/BB", 
                "<username>",
                "<password>")) {

            String sql = "<Update query to set status as new>";
            newPreparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            newPreparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If the only difference between the two halves of your code is the SQL query itself, then perhaps that (and only that) should be set at the beginning depending on `allDealsCreated`. I'd also only get the connection once, rather than in each iteration of your loop. That should simplify things.

Comment: @dave, can you please explain with the example

Comment: I didn't give you the code as I thought it would have been a good learning experience for you to try it out yourself rather than me hand-feed you. However, it looks like someone else has done just that :)

Comment: @dave, Thank you. So you are OK with Swaroop answer, but no changes?

Comment: Swaroop's answer _looks_ okay to me. Did it work when you tried it?

Comment: Yes it worked. I thought may be you can recommend any changes if you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with your code is you are creating Connection and PreparedStatements in for loop. That is not a best practice. Please follow below code.

```
    if (deals != null && !deals.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:as400://localhost/BB",
                    "<username>",
                    "<password>");
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
            String sql;
            if (allDealsCreated) {
                System.out.println("Updating the status of the deals as CLOSED");
                sql = "UPDATE DEALS SET STATUS = 'CLOSED' WHERE DEALNO= ?";
            } else {
                System.out.println("Updating the status of the deals as NEW");
                sql = "UPDATE DEALS SET STATUS = 'NEW' WHERE DEALNO= ?";
            }                    
            preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            for (String dealId : deals) {
                preparedStatement.setString(1, dealId);
                preparedStatement.addBatch();
            }
            preparedStatement.executeBatch();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I didnt get this point paramIndex = 0;
                <ADD_YOUR_PARAMETER>, parameter is already dealId right

Comment: Better than what I was about to answer, because it moves the `deals` check outside, so you aren't making a connection you won't use.

Comment: Do you have parameter to pass the query?

Comment: Yes swaroop. I want to pass the dealId in the query

Comment: @Yakhoob, Updated answer check now

Comment: @swarooppallapothu, so my query should be like this sql = "UPDATE DEALS SET STATUS = 'CLOSED' WHERE DEALNO= ?";

Comment: Yes swaroop. I have list of deals. Each deal should be updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156420/discussion-between-yakhoob-and-swaroop-pallapothu).